# Laravel 5 layout

Tags: php, layout, laravel-4, laravel-5

I was wondering what a general layout in Laravel 5 is like and if it is in L4 so I wrote some code. I've been using [teepluss/laravel-theme](https://github.com/teepluss/laravel-theme) but I want something of my own. If anyone could give me some ideas it would be useful.

### Controller.php:

```
<?php

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use DispatchesCommands, ValidatesRequests;

    protected $layout = null;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->setLayout();
    }

    protected function setPageContent($content)
    {
        if (is_null($this->layout)) {
            throw new Exception('layout was not set');
        }
        return view($this->layout, ['content' => view($content)]);
    }

    public function setLayout()
    {
        $lay = DB::table('layout')->where('selected', 1)->first();//i select the layout from a database
        return $this->layout = $lay->name . ".layouts." . $lay->name; //create a file with the database name
    }

    protected function setView($vista)
    {
        $view = DB::table('layout')->where('selected', 1)->first();
        return $view->name . '/' . $vista;
    }
}
```

After that I call getIndex() in MainController.php:

```
public function getIndex($page = null)
{
    if ($page == null) {
       return $this->setPageContent($this->setView('index')); 
    } else {
        return $this->setPageContent($this->setView($page));
    }
}
```

### routes.php:

```
Route::controller('/{page?}/{param?}', 'MainController');
```